# Variable set but not used

Tags: c

When compiling, I get the following error:

```
roadplan.c:64:11: error: variable 'thisRoad' set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
     Road *thisRoad = NULL;
```

The lines of interest here are (full function at the bottom of this post):

```c
Road *thisRoad = NULL;
----
/*    Create new road structure using new_road() function*/
        newRoad = new_road(org, dest, length);
        /*    Add it to the list of roads of the origin city.*/
        while (org -> roads -> next != NULL){
            thisRoad = org -> roads -> next;
        }
        thisRoad = newRoad;
```

when doing the obvious (deleting the declaration) I naturally get the error that the variable is not declared. Furthermore I've tried changing the name of the value. I've run out of ideas on how to fix this please help!

```c
static City *create_map (FILE *data_file)
{
    int num_of_cities, length, num_of_roads, i;
    char org_name[MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1], dest_name[MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1];
    
    City *map = NULL;
    City *org = map;
    City *dest = map;
    Road *newRoad = NULL;
    Road *thisRoad = NULL;

    /* Read in city-names   */
    fscanf (data_file, "%d", &num_of_cities);

    for (i = 0; i < num_of_cities; i++)
    {
        char city_name[MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1];
        City *city;
        City *c;

        fscanf (data_file, "%s", city_name);

        if (find_city (map, city_name) != NULL)
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "City %s already on the map\n", city_name);
            delete_map (map);
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        city = new_city (safe_strdup (city_name));

        if (map == NULL)
            /* This is the first city of the map */
            map = city;
        else {
            /* Find last of city list */
            c = map;
            while (c->next) c = c->next;
            /* And append new city there */
            c -> next = city;
        }
    }

         /* Read number of roads*/
    fscanf (data_file, "%d", &num_of_roads);
         /* For each road:*/
    for (i = 0; i<num_of_roads; i++) {
        /*    Read origin city name, destination city name and length*/
        fscanf(data_file, "%s %s %d", org_name, dest_name, &length);
        /*    Find pointers to orgin city structure and destination city structure*
         *    using the function find_city()*/
        org = find_city(map, org_name);
        dest = find_city(map, dest_name);
        /*    Create new road structure using new_road() function*/
        newRoad = new_road(org, dest, length);
        /*    Add it to the list of roads of the origin city.*/
        while (org -> roads -> next != NULL){
            thisRoad = org -> roads -> next;
        }
        thisRoad = newRoad;
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly whats wrong. It sees that it is declared, it also sees that it is set. But you never use the value inside as far as I can yee

Comment: Why do you put a value in `thisRoad` but never use it?

Comment: Style guide: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly
because they are [postfix operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3).
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing `org -> roads -> next` is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use `org->roads->next`.

Comment: Out of the problem associated to the error *set but not used* you (try to) read in your file without checking `fscanf` does not fail by checking the value it returns, nor protecting you against writing out of *city_name* and others because the read string is too long. This is dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make multiple assignments to `thisRoad`, but indeed never read any of those values from it.  This is clueing you in to a genuine issue with this code:

> ```
>         while (org -> roads -> next != NULL){
>             thisRoad = org -> roads -> next;
>         }
>         thisRoad = newRoad;
> ```

, which appears to be the only place you use `thisRoad`.  The compiler doesn't have sufficient pattern recognition to recognize what you're actually trying to do there, but it can observe that there are multiple assignments to `thisRoad`, but never any reads.  It supposes that if you assign a value then it's because at least sometimes you will want to read it back.

In this case, that loop will run either zero times or an unbounded number of times, because the loop body does nothing that would change the result of the loop condition.  It looks like you may be trying to append an element to a linked list, which would be more like this:

```
    Road *thisRoad = org->roads;     // Style: use the narrowest sufficient scope

    while (thisRoad->next != NULL) { // uses the value of thisRoad
        thisRoad = thisRoad->next;   // uses and modifies the value of thisRoad
    }
    thisRoad->next = newRoad;        // uses the value of thisRoad
```

Comment: Note also that the example code does not handle the case where `org->roads` is null.  The original code does not do that either, and it's unclear whether that's a case that can arise.